# Best way to center image+text w/ text to right and img to left

Tags: html, css

Here's a brief s/s of the html layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y9mR.jpg

I am using a page builder on wordpress so I am not very good with code

From what I read it seems like the best thing to do is to have the img as a seperate div and the text to have a seperate div and then do a bunch of positioning/alignment/float css stuff but i cant seem to get it to work

what is the simplest way to produce a result where both image and text are centered and the text is right of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flex.

```css
.con{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  align-items:center;
}
.con img{
  display:block;
  width:300px;
}
.con p{
  border:1px solid red;
  flex-grow:1;
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"/>
  <p>Could be a really long text here. Could be a really long text here.Could be a really long text here.Could be a really long text here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help...its working, do u know if the "flex" property work on all browsers and devices?

Comment: It supports all the new browsers and many of their previous browsers. see it here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: it is the simplest way and as the name is much flexible, if you wanna use it, please do accept the answer. If not then let me know, I will try to work around it.

Comment: seems great to me, i accepted the answer, thanks and good day to u